# Program is not looping

Tags: c, while-loop

I am trying to make the program print out "OK" for as long as i enter 'y' as a choice at the end, but it is not looping, it just prints out "OK" and ends the program even if i enter a 'y' at the end. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = 'y';
    while (c == 'y')
    {
        printf_s("OK\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &c);
        if (c != 'y')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are in windows system use [`fflush(stdin)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) before scanf

Comment: You might want to check [a `scanf_s` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

Comment: OK the fflush(stdin) helped when i wanted to keep the loop running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On first iteration when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then a newline character `\n` is passed to the input along with `y`. On second iteration `scanf_s` reads `\n`.
Change

```
scanf_s("%c", &c);
```

to

```
scanf_s(" %c", &c);  
         ^Notice the space before %c
```

A space before `%c` specifier can consume any number of white-space characters.

Comment: The `scanf_s` method requires that all storage locations be followed with an explicit size.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `scanf_s` line as follows

```
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
```

This extra parameter is specifying the size of the `c` argument.  Plain old `scanf` doesn't require this argument but the versions ending with `_s` do

Also the `if` block with the `break` statement is unnecessary because the conditional on the `while` loop effectively does the same thing.  It could be written as follows

```
while (c == 'y')
{
    printf_s("OK\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I used scanf instead of scanf_s, that solved the problem, thanks everyone.

Comment: if you want to continue using `scanf_s` see my answer as it corrects the usage of htis API

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with scanf

if you use like this u will see it is working ..

```
       #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 1;
    while (c == 1)
    {
        printf_s("OK\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &c);
        if (c != 1)
        {
            printf_s("hello\n");
                continue;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He is not "wrong" with scanf.  You can scan for a character.

Comment: He was using scanf_s to scan for a character.  Changing it to an int does not help him solve the issue with his scanf_s not having the necessary third parameter.  He is not "You are wrong with scanf "

Comment: I said that he is using it wrongly if he get with %c compilers reads new line as a char too. That's why he is using wrongly!

Comment: Then add more explanation to your answer instead of simply stating "wrong".

Answer (score -1):

Put a space before `%c` to skip whitespace.